# How to use removeClass according to multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone help me out with this animation? I have been trying to replicate this one. I got so close to completing it but just can't find a way to make the animation endless on every click. Huge, Thanks in advance!

Problem: After two clicks my animation transitioning of div elements away from the window does not seem to be working.

Expected Result: One every click the Background should transitioning into the window just like the reference from Instagram that I have linked you with.

[Reference](https://www.instagram.com/p/BcoyW5PFXgx/?taken-by=manchesterunited)

[Here is the Demo Link](https://codepen.io/sathyaappu/pen/xpGZKB)

```
<div class="bg">
  <div id="blue" class="skew"></div>
  <div id="red" class="skew"></div>
  <div id="blue_2" class="skew"></div>
</div>

<button>Toggle</button>

$skew: skew(-10deg);

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skew {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  &.blue_wrapper {
    background: blue;
    animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
  }
  &.red_wrapper {
    background: red;
    animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
  }
  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: inherit;
    background: inherit;
    transform: $skew;
  }
  &::before {
    left: -5%;
  }
  &::after {
    right: -5%;
  }
}

#red,
#blue_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

blue_2.blue_wrapper_2 {
  background: blue;
  animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-110%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    if (
      $("#blue").hasClass("blue_wrapper")
    ) {
      $("#red").addClass("red_wrapper");
    } else if (
      $("#blue").hasClass("skew blue_wrapper") &&
      $("#red").hasClass("skew red_wrapper")
    ) {
      $("skew red_wrapper").removeClass("red_wrapper");
      $("skew blue_wrapper").removeClass("blue_wrapper");
      $("blue_2").addClass("blue_wrapper_2");
    } else if {
      $("#blue_2").hasClass("blue_wrapper_2")
    ) {
      $("#red").removeClass("red_wrapper");
      $("#blue").removeClass("blue_wrapper");
    } else {
      $("#blue").addClass("blue_wrapper");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: **`+`** is not a proper conditional operator and `hasClass("")` makes no sense

Comment: `$("#blue").hasClass("skew blue_wrapper")` is an invalid option for `hasClass`.  You can do either `$("#blue.skew").hasClass("blue_wrapper")` or `$("#blue").hasClass("skew") && $("#blue").hasClass("blue_wrapper")` OR `!!$("#blue.skew.blue_wrapper").length` OR `$("#blue").is(".skew .blue_wrapper")`

Answer (score 0):

You logic makes no sense for

```
else if (
   $("#blue").hasClass("") +
   $("#red").hasClass("") +
   $("#blue_2").hasClass("blue_wrapper_2")
   ) {
   $("#red").removeClass("red_wrapper");
   $("#blue").removeClass("blue_wrapper");
```

In the above you are checking if the classes have no class then removing the class that is lnt there.

Also you are using + when I assume you meant && or ||

Comment: Yep, I tried with && and || operators and did not get anywhere and ended up losing patience. If you could help that'd be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Demo link isn't working because you aren't removing the blue Wrapper or red wrapper, this will get the demo to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#blue").hasClass("blue_wrapper")) {
        $("#red").addClass("red_wrapper");
        $("#blue").removeClass("blue_wrapper");
     } else {
       $("#blue").addClass("blue_wrapper");
       $("#red").removeClass("red_wrapper");
     }
  });
});
```

For your regular code, you should replace + with && or || as needed, and remove wrappers that you add.

Answer (score 0):

Some syntax issues, some selector issues.  Compiled the CSS to test.  Removed one odd CSS thing that would not compile.  Note I modified to use lime to start to better illustrate.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button.toggle").on("click", function() {
    if (
      $("#blue").hasClass("blue_wrapper") && !$("#red").hasClass("red_wrapper")
    ) {
      $("#red").addClass("red_wrapper");
    } else if (
      $("#blue").hasClass("blue_wrapper") &&
      $("#red").hasClass("red_wrapper")
    ) {
      $(".red_wrapper").removeClass("red_wrapper");
      $(".blue_wrapper").removeClass("blue_wrapper");
      $("#blue_2").addClass("blue_wrapper_2");
    } else if (
      $("#blue_2").hasClass("blue_wrapper_2")
    ) {
      $("#red").removeClass("red_wrapper");
      $("#blue").removeClass("blue_wrapper");
       $("#blue_2").removeClass("blue_wrapper_2")
   } else {
      $("#blue").addClass("blue_wrapper");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.skew {
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: lime;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.skew {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.skew.blue_wrapper {
  background: blue;
  animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
}
.skew.red_wrapper {
  background: red;
  animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
}
.skew::before,
.skew::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  transform: $skew;
}
.skew::before {
  left: -5%;
}
.skew::after {
  right: -5%;
}
#red,
#blue_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#blue_2.blue_wrapper_2 {
  background: blue;
  animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
@keyframes slideRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-110%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">
  <div id="blue" class="skew">blue</div>
  <div id="red" class="skew">red</div>
  <div id="blue_2" class="skew">blue_2</div>
</div>

<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: This is almost good but I think it reset completely on the 3rd click. This is satisfying! If you could help out in completing it flawlessly that'd be awesome! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It cycles back to the start - which is what you see.  Not sure what you desired it to do - seems odd to just get "stuck" at that final point but you could alter it to your needs.